# Add Text To Floating Action Button Web

Tags: javascript, css, materialize

I am using materialize css on the web. I have implemented its floating action button. Its working pperfectly like so 
[image: MATERIALIZE FAB]

What I however want is one with text on it, like in this android app

[image: MATERIALIZE FAB]

Anyone knows how I can achieve this on the web?

Comment: Just create it yourself using vanilla css.  It looks like a few divs with some styling of border radius, box-shadow, and some choice positioning and grouping in your html.  You could knock those out no problem and just align them to be next to their respective buttons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Materializecss - Always show tooltips with action button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36542634/materializecss-always-show-tooltips-with-action-button)